# python date from datetime

Tags: datetime, date, python-2.7, jinja2

How do you get just the date part from a datetime value to show in an html template.

[This link shows what I want with a lambda, but I don't know how to use lambdas to assign values to a variable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata)

Comment: The lambda in the link is converting a string date to a `date` object. Do you have a string, or a datetime?

Comment: I have a db.DateProperty() and I want to show only the month day and year, but appengine converts db.DateProperty() to a datetime value.

Comment: This is actually an example in the jinja2 documentation; you can create a custom formatter and then just pass the datetime to your template and use the formatter to display only the date: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters

Comment: Wooble, this custom filter looks perfect. I don't understand in the example what this means: "You can register it on the template environment by updating the filters dict on the environment:

environment.filters['datetimeformat'] = datetimeformat". Where is the filters dict accessed? Thanks.

Comment: Where `environment` is your jinja2 environment, it's just `environment.filters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an example in the jinja2 documentation; you can create a custom formatter and then just pass the datetime to your template and use the formatter to display only the date: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters – Wooble 22 hours ago

I am adding Wooble's comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
d= datetime.datetime.now()
print d.strftime("%A %B %d, %Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

As appengine uses datetime objects, you can extract a date object from it using `datetime.date()`

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date

Then you can use `date.__str__()` or `date.strftime()` to construct the string you need.

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime